# Royal Slider put a div inside another div Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Royal Slider and I would like to put the below div inside my websites container div.

```
<div class="rsGCaption"></div>
```

How do I go about it?

**Current JS code**

```
(function(b) {
    b.extend(b.rsProto, {
        _d6: function() {
            var a = this;
            a.st.globalCaption && (a.ev.on("rsAfterInit", function() {
                a.globalCaption = b('<div class="rsGCaption"></div>').appendTo(a.st.globalCaptionInside ? a._e1 : a.slider);
                a.globalCaption.html(a.currSlide.caption)
            }), a.ev.on("rsBeforeAnimStart", function() {
                a.globalCaption.html(a.currSlide.caption)
            }))
        }
    });
    b.rsModules.globalCaption = b.rsProto._d6
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: did you uglify your JS code here? That's not helping.

Comment: I just copied it from the file